# Изменение названия командной строки

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, ctypes

Использую библиотеку ctypes для изменения названия.
При попытке вставить переменную которая выдаёт числовое значение, он его не выводит.
Код:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    text = f.read()
    lines = text.count('\n') + 1

ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleA(b"GAME | With balance: ", str(lines), b" | All: ", lines)
```

Может есть у кого идеи реализации?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Может, надо тоже в b перевести

Comment: SetConsoleTitleA принимает один параметр (одну байтовую строку), вы передаете 4 параметра, как будто это обычный print.

Comment: @insolor, какие тогда есть ещё вариации принта данной переменной?

Comment: print тут вообще не нужен. Я к тому, что нужно собрать все в одну строку (один параметр), потом его передать в функцию. Грубо говоря, должны быть плюсы вместо запятых, ну и все данные должны быть одного типа - или байты, или строки.

Answer (score 0):

Прочёл новую документацию, теперь, если используется python 3, то можно пользоваться - SetConsoleTitleW.
Является версией Unicode функции SetConsoleTitle. Таким образом, вы можете использовать Unicode и вам больше не нужно кодировать строку / переменную в байтовый объект. Вы можете просто заменить аргумент строковой переменной.